# how to validate values of a column with column of another table which is not a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `DRIVER` with a column having following specification
`BranchPostedAt int not null`

In another table viz. `CompanyBranch`, I have following column 
`BranchId  int not null`

In the second table viz. `CompanyBranch`, primary key is set on two columns as under

```
CompanyId  int not null
BranchId   int not null
```

Is there any way by which I can set a foreign reference key on `dbo.Driver.BranchPostedId` referencing `dbo.CompanyBranch.BranchId` at the time of creating `dbo.Driver`?

Any help?

Comment: Yes, there is. Make sure you create `CompanyBranch` first. What's the problem?

Comment: i have already done that. But while creating dbo.Driver how to set foreign key on column BranchPostedAt which in  term will refer to column BranchId of dbo.CompanyBranch because this column is not the primary key in dbo.CompanyBranch.

Comment: is `BranchId` unique in `CompanyBranch` or someother table?

Comment: instead of using a composite key, make `BranchId` a primary key and your  problem is solved.

Comment: @ughai, No BranchId is not unique in dbo.CompanyBranch. But I have another table viz. dbo.CityMaster with a column CityId  int not null which is a primary key. Incidentally column dbo.CompanyBranch.BranchId referes to dbo.CityMaster.CityId as foreign key. But all rows in dbo.CityMaster are not there in dbo.CompanyBranch. Any suggetions?

Comment: then `DRIVER(BranchPostedAt)` should have a foreign key to `dbo.CityMaster(CityId)` and not `CompanyBranch`

Comment: @Tanner, can not do that as in dbo.CompanyMaster I might have a row representing CompanyId 1 & BranchId 1 and another row representing CompanyId 2 & BranchId 1.

Comment: @ughai, In dbo.CityMaster there are many rows reflecting various cities. But company may not have its Branch in all the Cities as mentioned in dbo.CityMaster. Hence setting foreign key reference on DRIVER(BranchPostedAt) with dbo.CityMaster.CityId will be logically incorrect.

Comment: @lalu, - you'll have to create a new unique key (it can even be an identity) and reference that. Check second option in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to [create a trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx), but this is a little messy. I prefer previous posters answer to create a new identiy primary key on CompanyBranch [CompanyBranchId] and reference that as a foreign key.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trDriver
   ON  DRIVER
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS(Select * 
              from CompanyBranch cb
              Inner join inserted i on i.BranchPostedAt = cb.BranchId )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('The BranchPostedAt is not in the CompanyBranch table.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN
    END

END
GO
```

Comment: But BranchId is not primary key in dbo.CompanyBranch and as such this statement generates an error  Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.CompanyBranch' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_DRIVER'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: understood. amended answer to reflect.

Comment: since new to SQL my knowledge of triggers is very limited. but shall update myself about it & try your suggestion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just added an example trigger. I haven't tested it but it should serve as a starter.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. To create a foreign key, the key that you "reference" to in the other table must be a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint.

You can consider few options:

1. Make BranchId in CompanyBranch table as Unique
2. Create a new PRIMARY KEY in CompanyBranch - CompanyBranchId, and
   reference it in your Driver table

Comment: No BranchId is not unique in dbo.CompanyBranch. But I have another table viz. dbo.CityMaster with a column CityId int not null which is a primary key. Incidentally column dbo.CompanyBranch.BranchId referes to dbo.CityMaster.CityId as foreign key. But all rows in dbo.CityMaster are not there in dbo.CompanyBranch. Any suggetions?

Comment: @Lalu, based on your comments for other answers, I understand you need company & branch as single entity, the best way forward would be to go with my second suggestion and create a new PRIMARY Key in CompanyBranch - "CompanyBranchId".

Comment: That seems to be the only solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Question and Comments, This is what you have

```
TABLE dbo.CityMaster
    CityId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

TABLE dbo.CompanyBranch
    CompanyID INT NOT NULL,
    BranchID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.CityMaster(CityId),
    CONSTRAINT PK... PRIMARY KEY (CompanyID,BranchID)

TABLE dbo.DRIVER
    BranchPostedAt INT NOT NULL,
```

Now, Since `BranchID` references `CityMaster.City` column and `BranchID` is not a `unique` column in `dbo.CompanyBranch`, You cannot use `BranchID` as a Foreign key reference for your `DRIVER.BranchPostedAt`.

**Option 1**

You should use `dbo.CityMaster` which contain the master list of values which will be stored in `DRIVER.BranchPostedAt`.

**Option 2**

If you want to `dbo.CompanyBranch`, you would then have to create a new unique column(you can even use an `identity` column to make it transparent) may be `CompanyBranchID` (apart from your existing composite key) and use it as a foreign key reference. Your existing composite key cannot be used as is.

Answer (score 0):

having CompanyBranch Table only is meaningfull when you have more than one Company and also there is possibility that companies share branches with each other, otherwise you don't need such table. you just then have Company and Branch Tables and in Branch Table, BranchID is unique and you have a foreign key CompanyID in Branch Table Too.

Comment: Yes multiple companies of same group may have their branch located in the same city. Hence can not separate tables for company & branches.

Comment: you mean you don't have separate company and branch tables? is your database already in normalized form?

Comment: No they are not separate tables. Database is still under construction.

Comment: incidentally just started migrating from Foxpro to SQL & may be that is why my logic while building database & tables is influenced by my Foxpro knowledge / background.

Comment: so if you create separate Tables Company and Branch base your existing data then you have a normal form database and you can reference Branch table in your Driver Table instead of CompanyBranch that is the correct resolution.

Comment: But then I will not be able to control company & branch as single entity. If i create separate tables for company & branch then it would lead to crashing of the system in a situation when a user might while entering a txn refer to company 1 (ABC Pvt. Ltd.) & Branch 5 (New Delhi). This two separately are valid entries in respective tables. But then company 1 (ABC Pvt. Ltd.) has no branch in New Delhi.

Comment: I do not mean to remove the CompanyBranch Table, it will exists and it will maintain the relation between Company and Branch Table and will have their IDs as foreign keys inside, that will reference Company and Branch Table primary keys.